# How to use Python the sum of the previous 3 rows until the very end?

Tags: python

I would like to sum of the previous 3 rows until the very end.

For example:

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 7 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 3 |

What I want:

| Number | Value | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 8 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 13 |
| 4 | 2 | 11 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 | 12 |
| 7 | 2 | 12 |
| 8 | 4 | 13 |
| 9 | 7 | 13 |
| 10 | 1 | 12 |
| 11 | 3 | 11 |

Thanks

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Pandas, what you want is `rolling`:

```
df['Output'] = df['Value'].rolling(3).sum()
```

it gives as expected:

```
    Number   Value  Output
0         1      4     NaN
1         2      8     NaN
2         3      1    13.0
3         4      2    11.0
4         5      3     6.0
5         6      7    12.0
6         7      2    12.0
7         8      4    13.0
8         9      7    13.0
9        10      1    12.0
10       11      3    11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of numbers and you would like to sum the previous 3 rows until the very end, you could use the following code:

```
# Initialize the result list
result = []

# Loop through the list
for i in range(len(list)):
    # Calculate the sum of the previous 3 elements
    sum_3_prev = sum(list[i-3:i])
    
    # Append the sum to the result list
    result.append(sum_3_prev)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

This will produce a list of the sum of the previous 3 elements for each element in the original list.